# CQRS - options around "get or create"

Tags: oop, architecture, cqrs

I'm putting something together using a CQRS pattern (no event sourcing, nor DDD, but a clear difference between command and query).

The operation I'm trying to model is a "get-or-create", given a set of parameters.  The item being created (or gotten) is effectively a unique communications link ID.  Either of two parties can say "get-or-create comms link between me and the other" and a new temporary random ID is returned (which would be valid between them both).  They can then send/receive messages using that ID (a `PostMessage` command or `GetRecentMessages` query).  This temporary ID can be passed around, but can also be centrally invalidated, controlled, etc.  Different sessions between the two parties should be recorded separately.

I know that the more typical "insert-then-get-me-the-ID-back" is handled by the command having a GUID parameter.  But this doesn't seem to apply here because of course the item might already exist..

My options, I believe:

1. Execute a `GetOrCreateCommsLink` command followed by a `GetActiveCommsLinkId` query, i.e. command, then query.  Feels wrong because commands are supposedly typically asynchronous (though not in my simple prototype so far), and is it right to wait for a command then run a query in my service layer?
2. Run a `GetExistingOrNewActiveCommsLinkId` query, which will either return an existing session ID, or create and return one.  Feels wrong because it's a dirty cheat, both reading and mutating state in a query..
3. Don't use CQRS for this part of the app
4. Have each client use their own ID for the session - `NotifyCommsLinkIdentifier` command from each side specifies the parameters and their own ID, which is linked internally to the actual ID by the command.  Then run a `GetUnderlyingCommsLinkId` query, given the identifier previously specified, to uncover the ID if needed.  Feels wrong to because inventing this extra concept seems to be only because of the CQRS pattern, rather than any actual domain/business need

I suppose my question in general is how to deal with potential get-then-act, or act-then-get scenarios.  Should I simply chain them together in my service layer, as per option 1.

Is there a standard approach, or standard approaches, to this?

Comment: Anyone like to explain a downvote? Seems a reasonable question?

Answer (score 2):

So you are talking about CQS, not CQRS. Basically you are trying to find workarounds in order to strictly implement CQS pattern for something that naturally may not really be an asynchronous command.

My advice is: don't try to apply a pattern because of the pattern, but because it makes sense. Does it make sense in your case? What would be the benefit? Remember that you are not Amazon. Do you really need it?

That said, what I typically do is not the purist way, but allowing a command to return a simple ID if it's needed. This will make your architecture a lot more simple; and you still separate commands from queries which to me is the most important advantage.

Comment: That's great, thanks.  In working with CQS/CQRS so far I'm getting great vibes from just moving away from large monolithic services, instead having nice separate commands and queries - with each type benefitting from specific additional framework features I build.  DDD would do similar, but requires more OOP expertise across the team I feel.  So I like it, but am happy for someone else to reassure that it's not blasphemy to mix techniques as required..

Comment: (By the first part I meant it's not scalability, but clean, readable - and actually nicely testable - code and functionality that's the main reason for looking at these patterns)